# ¿Se puede volver a conectar cliente TCP en el mismo puerto en poco tiempo en C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

Tengo un dispositivo en el que se configura obligatoriamente su IP y puerto, y también el IP y puerto del PC al que se quiere conectar y enviar los datos, vía TCP. 
El problema es que el dispositivo funciona como maestro TCP y yo debo de iniciar la conexión. Y siendo la primera ejecución del programa no hay problema, pero si en menos de 4 minutos (tiempo de `TIME_WAIT`) vuelvo a iniciar el programa me da el error :

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Si debo de utilizar siempre el mismo puerto para que me envíe los datos, ¿se puede invalidar la conexión TCP de la ejecución anterior, o alguna otra manera para volver a utilizar el mismo par ip-puerto en un periodo corto de tiempo?

Comment: ¿de que dispositivo estamos  hablando? podria ser una limitacion propia del dispositivo, o que estas originando siempre del mismo puerto, ademas ¿Como cierras la conexión?, si TIME_WAIT es en el dispositivo, significa que esta esperando el cierre del otro extremo, en ese caso podrías acortar el tiempo cerrando la conexion de forma ordenada.

Comment: Es una pesadora, yo solo puedo consultar el TIME_WAIT en el pc, por lo que no se lo que hace el dispositivo en el otro extremo. De momento tengo puesto en el destructor de la clase que cierre la conexion (funcion tcpClient.Close()) y se ejecuta pero no se llega a cerrar correctamente ya que al volver a ejecutar la aplicacion me sale el error y debo esperar los 4 minutos del TIME_WAIT

Comment: Prueba de mover el código de cierre a un punto después de hacer la transmisión, el destructor no se invoca haya que el Garbaje colector lo decida. Eso puede retrasar que sea invocado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar una conexión TCP cuando quieras, las veces que quieras, sólo asegúrate de terminar la conexión anterior antes de establecer una nueva que creo es el problema por el cual estas teniendo el error que mencionas. Como dato, esta demás mencionar el lenguaje de programación en este caso ya que un protocolo es independiente del lenguaje.

Adjunto un esquema de comunicación TCP para que puedas revisarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La necesidad de terminar la conexión la sabía, pero en el destructor de la clase ya cierro la conexión tcp, aunque no funciona correctamente, visto lo visto. Y lo de poner el lenguaje es más por si alguien tiene el código específico para cerrar correctamente o machacar la conexión anterior.

Answer (score 0):

***Puedes iniciar las siguientes conexiones usando otros puertos, evitando la falla.***

*Las conexiones usan puertos por protocolos, así las aplicaciones/desempeños guardan un orden para no interferir entre sí, este es el mismo motivo por el que no puedes tener dos conexiones con el mismo - protocolo de red, dirección y puerto - .*

Las conexiones TCP usan acuse de recibo por paquetes de datos, por lo que al forzar cerrar el proceso, la transferencia puede quedar incompleta. Para cerrar el proceso adecuadamente, habría de controlarse que se hayan completado las transferencias de datos, que no queden procesos de transferencia en curso, cerrando la conexión de forma ordenada. O bien forzar el cierre sabiendo que se pueden truncar transferencias, consciente de lo que conlleva, si lo que queremos en ese momento es precisamente abortar la sesión (por puerto y direcciones).

Para cerrar una conexion en C# con TcpClient sería así :

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

...
...
   networkStream.Close();
   tcpClient.Close();
...
```

Comment: Referente al último párrafo, en una conexión TCP si cierras una conexión antes de que termine una transferencia de datos __no implica en nada__ en una siguiente conexión. Solo pierdes datos, nada mas que eso.

Comment: Según el mensaje de error, estaría usando la misma dirección mac, IP y el mismo puerto TCP, cuando trata de iniciar de nuevo exactamente el mismo proceso que está abierto, creo que eso es lo que provoca el error. Claro que si usara otro puerto podría iniciar muchas más conexiones, siempre que el dispositivo lo soporte.

Comment: Cierto, y viendo el mensaje de error, usando otros puertos puede tener más conexiones a la vez.

Comment: El `tcpClient.Close();`lo hago pero no se llega a cerrar la conexion parece ser, y el `networkStream.Close();` no lo hago y que esta en otro hilo y no puedo acceder a ella desde el destructor de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera agregar como dato que es muy importante tener idea de que dispositivo estamos hablando. En mi caso tuve la oportunidad de desarrollar una aplicación en .NET para un lector biométrico de huellas que trabajaba por medio de sockets TCP pero era mediante una API. En tal caso yo con un timer lo consulto cada X cantidad de segundos que yo quiera ya que en realidad no debo abrir y cerrar la conexión para consultar.

Esto último también puede serte útil, cambiar la forma en que trabajas para que el programa no cierre y abra sino que mantenga y consulte o escriba.

Solo una humilde opinion.

Saludos.

Comment: Es una pesadora, a la que me conecto y me manda los pesos cuando se lo solicito enviándole una trama especifica. La conexión la mantengo abierta todo el rato ya que si la cierro y abro supongo que el problema se mantendria